# create a scheme function that returns the average of negative numbers in a list

Tags: scheme, computer-science

I'm trying to find the answer of my question but I can't find anything in the Internet. Can anyone please tell me how to write this function?
Thank you very much.

Comment: These are separate steps; 1) filter out the non-negative numbers from the list; 2) sum the numbers of that list; 3) compute how many numbers are left; 4) compute the average. You have probably solved most of these problems recently in different contexts.

Answer (score -1):

It's very easy. You can do it recursively:

```
(define (helper lst sum count)
  ...)
```

The helper does this using either `cond` of nested `if`:

1. as a base case when the list is empty it uses the values `sum` and `count` to calculate the average. eg. `(helper '() -4 2) ; ==> -2`
2. We know the list has at least one element. Check if the first element is negative. If so then it recurses with the rest of `lst` and using the sum of previous `sum` and the element and as `count` you increase the previous by 1. eg. `(helper '(-1) 0 0) ; ==> (helper '() -1 1) ; ==> -1`
3. just recruse with the rest of `lst` and keep the same values as `sum` and `count`. `(helper '(1) -1 1) ; ==> -1`

Now when you got this working you can just include it in your actual function and use it:

```
(define (average-negative lst)
  (define (helper lst sum count)
    ...)

  (helper lst 0 0))
```

Test

```
(average-negative '(-1))         ; ==> -1
(avwerage-negative '(1 -2 3 -4)) ; ==> -3
```

And for the brave:

```
(average-negative '())           ; ==> ??
```